# C# Guessing Game - Windows Form App - How to configure a 'PlayAgainButton' and keep total score

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I'm new with c# and I need some help with my little app.

I want to have a button which starts the game over again after you are done, but the program needs to keep the total score. (you receive points for guessing)

Thanks in advance,

Philip

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace GuessingGame
{
 public partial class TheUltimateGuessingGame : Form
 {

    public TheUltimateGuessingGame()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    int number;
    int numberoftries;
    int points;
    int total = 0;
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Random generator = new Random();
        number = generator.Next(0, 101);

        MessageBox.Show("Try to guess a number between 1 and 100");
    }

    private void PlayAgainButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button_guess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int guess = Convert.ToInt32(textBox_guess.Text);

        if (guess > number)
        {
            textbox_showdifference.Text = ("Guess was too high, try again!");
        }

        if (guess < number)
        {
            textbox_showdifference.Text = ("Guess was too low, try again!");
        }

        if (guess == number)
        {
            textbox_showdifference.Text = ("Awesome, guess was right!");

            MessageBox.Show("It took you " + Convert.ToString(numberoftries) + " tries 
            to guess the right number");

            if (numberoftries <= 3)
            {
                points = 10;
            }

            if (numberoftries >= 4 && numberoftries <= 6)
            {
                points = 5;
            }

            if (numberoftries >= 7)
            {
                points = 2;
            }

            total = total + points;

            ScoreBoard1.Text = ("Here are your points --> " + points + "\nHere are your total points --> " + total);
        }
        ++numberoftries;


    }

     private void exitbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not this?

```
private void PlayAgainButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Random generator = new Random();
    number = generator.Next(0, 101);
    numberoftries = 0;
    MessageBox.Show("Try to guess a number between 1 and 100");
}
```

`InitializeComponent` is the method that parses your XAML to build the form. It's not intended to reset the state of your object.